# AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'email'

Tags: python, mongodb, flask

```
@app.route("/login", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
            def login():
                if current_user.is_authenticated:
                    return redirect(url_for('home'))
                form = LoginForm()
                if form.validate_on_submit():
                    users = mongo.db.users
                    loginuser_json = users.find_one({'email': form.email.data})
                    if loginuser_json and bcrypt.check_password_hash(loginuser_json['password'], form.password.data):
                        # Create a custom user and pass it to login_user:
                        loginuser = User(loginuser_json)
                        login_user(loginuser,duration=d)
                        next_page = request.args.get('next')
                        return redirect(next_page) if next_page else redirect(url_for('home'))
                        return redirect(url_for('home'))
                    else:
                        flash('Login Unsuccessful. Please check username and password', 'danger')
                return render_template('login.html', title='Login', form=form)
```

This is the code that i have written for login functionality and its working fine

```
@app.route("/posts/new",methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def new_post():
    form=PostForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        post = mongo.db.post
        title=form.title.data
        content=form.content.data
        author=current_user.email
        mypost={'title' : title, 'content' :content,'author':author}
        post.insert(mypost)
        flash('Your post has been created','success')
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
    return render_template('createpost.html', title='Create Post', form=form)
```

And this is the code for creating post and saving it to mongoDB with author name which is the current_user which is loggedin
This code gives an error AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'email'

What should i do ?

USER MODEL

```
class User(UserMixin):
def __init__(self, user_json):
    self.user_json = user_json

# Overriding get_id is required if you don't have the id property
# Check the source code for UserMixin for details
def get_id(self):
    object_id = self.user_json.get('email')
    return str(object_id)
def get_mail(self): 
    return self.user_json.get('email')
```

Comment: Can you post your `User` model too?

Comment: i have edited my post and add it

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here:

```
loginuser_json = users.find_one({'email': form.email.data})
```

You look for `email`

But you store it in  `àuthor`

```
 author=current_user.email
 mypost={'title' : title, 'content' :content,'author':author}
```

change store with:

```
 mypost={'title' : title, 'content' :content,'email':author}
```

Comment: author=current_user.email
        mypost={'title' : title, 'content' :content,'email':author}
like this?

Comment: same error i have wrote the solution that you have mentioned

Comment: Can you give use the value of `loginuser_json ` ?

Comment: I have found the solution 
I created a method in User Class and use that method in post route 
Thanks for the help